# Color detection in a static image - OpenCV Android

Tags: android, opencv

I have an image with four squares red, green, blue and yellow. I need to get the rgb values of each squares. I'm able to get the rgb of the whole image, but i want it for a specific section.

- The image which i am going to get will be from the camera and stored onto the SDCard

Comment: Have you tried cropping the specific area and detecting color?

Comment: you need to show areas in the image and show their rgb values, am i right?

Comment: @IsmetAlkan i just want to get all the four sections rgb specifically and not* going to display it anywhere

Comment: @Torcellite Not cropped but i tried providing images containing only R, only G and only B... and i got the right rgbs for them.. Basically i'm getting the average rgb color of the image.

Comment: @aditya Are the squares always going to be in the same positions? I mean the colors of the squares can change but their respective positions does not alter, if so, your best bet would be to crop and detect.

Comment: @Torcellite actually cropping and detecting would ask me to use the OpenCV library... I'm looking for a way if this task can be accomplish using simple android APIs like Bitmap and BitmapFactory

Comment: @aditya Do check out the answer.

Comment: I'm very new to Opencv & trying to find the  red circular color present in an image.How do i achieve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I understand you exactly, but here it comes.

You need to create BufferedImage object to get RGB value:

```
File f = new File(yourFilePath);
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(f);
```

You can get RGB Color values from the image from then. You have 4 squares; to check their RGB values, you can check the corner pixels' RGB values:

```
Color leftTop = new Color(img.getRGB(0, 0));
Color rightTop = new Color(img.getRGB(img.getWidth - 1, 0));
Color leftBottom = new Color(img.getRGB(0, img.getHeight - 1));
Color rightBottom = new Color(img.getRGB(img.getWidth - 1, img.getHeight - 1));
```

After that it's easy to get red, green and blue values individually:

```
int red = leftTop.getRed();
int green = leftTop.getGreen();
int blue = leftTop.getBlue();
```

**EDIT:**
I'm really sorry, I didn't see it's for Android. As you said, Android doesn't have ImageIO class. To accomplish the task in Android, first initialize the image:

```
Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(yourFilePath);
```

From then the operation is pretty much the same:

```
int leftTop = img.getPixel(0, 0);
...

int red = Color.red(pixel);
int blue = Color.blue(pixel);
int green = Color.green(pixel);
```

Comment: Thanks for the support... i am trying this out.. i'll just get back to you then..

Comment: BufferedImage & ImageIO is not supported in Android SDK... Now i am looking for if Bitmap class could do this for me.

Comment: you changed my approach completely... I am getting the top and bottom corners pixels rgb... Lets see if things will workout with this way.. M not accepting the answer for now but surely a +1 for you.. Thanks for the help mate..

Answer (score 1):

Use [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228812/crop-image-android-android) to crop your image.

Now to detect the color of the image take a pixel from the square and detect it's color with [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807360/how-to-get-pixel-colour-in-android).

After finding the RGB value use a simple conditional statement to see if the square is red blue or green.

Comment: Thanks for the help... But i need not have to do this all.. Thanks again. +1 for your help.

Comment: Check out my answer... Where in i get four sample corner pixels and their rgbs.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I got it this way

```
int topLeftIndex = squareImage.getPixel(0, 0);
int R1 = (topLeftIndex >> 16) & 0xff;
int G1 = (topLeftIndex >> 8) & 0xff;
int B1  = topLeftIndex  & 0xff;
```

and same way with

```
int bottomLeftIndex=squareImage.getPixel(0, picHeight - 1);
int topRightIndex=squareImage.getPixel(picWidth -1 , 0);
int bottomRightIndex=squareImage.getPixel(picWidth -1, picHieght - 1);
```