# Detect all color of Image in android

Tags: android, image, image-processing

I have to extract all color of image in Android without using ML (Google vision, IBM Visual Recognition).

I had check below option.

**1.[Palette](https://developer.android.com/training/material/palette-colors)**
The palette library attempts to extract the following six color profiles.

**2. Get color of a particular pixel**

```
public static int getDominantColor(Bitmap bitmap) {
Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 1, 1, true);
final int color = newBitmap.getPixel(0, 0);
newBitmap.recycle();
return color;
}
```

if I break bitmap in small size then find out color and save in list.
Then there is time taken and OutOfMemoryError.

Please suggest any library  to find color of images.

**Edit**

Pick from gallary

```
 InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                        data.getData());
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                stream.close()
```

Get Color code from Pixel

```
HashMap<Integer,Integer> colorList=new HashMap<>();
private void  getAllColorInImages(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    colorList.clear();
    if(bitmap==null)
        return;
    int width=bitmap.getWidth();
    int height=bitmap.getHeight();
    for(int i=0;i<width;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<height;j++)
        {
            final int color = bitmap.getPixel(i, j);
            colorList.put(color,color);

        }
    }
    System.out.println("color list size "+colorList.size());
    System.out.println("color list Name "+colorList);

}
```

Comment: Do you need each and every colour used in bitmap or just one average colour of image?

Comment: Every color. It is use for analysis purpose. if i search a particular color in image and that color is in small part of image then we will miss in case of average

Comment: Also, what is the exact thing you're trying to achieve? E.g. Finding number of pixels in image with some color.

Comment: There are certain things which are to be done using the native code, your requirement falls under that category, if you are concerned with performance and efficiency, try using OpenCV refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16643243/4878972)

Comment: @AseemSharma Answer is not related to openCV and it similar to find colar and each pixel and save in list.

Comment: @AadityaBrahmbhatt  Find out all color in image or specific color exist in image

Comment: @mukesh if you get the number of colors of each pixel then you can group them and detect available colors in the image or what?

Comment: @AseemSharma time taken process and  outofMemoryError

Comment: Can you post your code where you get an  "outofMemoryError"? This can probably be fixed

Comment: @TA Not always. it is on some devices. I have edit the code. Please review it

Comment: Calculate the histogram of the image. Colors present in the image correspond to non-zero bins.

Comment: I understand that you need ALL colours in bitmap but you are not realising that bitmap itself is collection of different colours! Do you want to sort colours, find most used colour etc. Also why are you storing key and value both same in your hashmap?