# How to crop image using coordinates in android?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hi i can able to crop image either rectangle shape or vowel shape,here in both case  4 coordiante points based those points we are cropping image those are left  middle  point,right side middle point,top and bottom middle point but,my requirement is i need to crop image based on 8 coordinates,what above i mentioned those 4 coordinates and remain 4 is top of image starting edge 1 coordinate and top of image ending corner 1 coordinate,bottom of image starting one coordinate,ending of image another coordidnate,then image we can  crop different shapes,so i don't know how to crop images using 8 coordinates...using below code i can able crop image using 4 coordinates....any one help me please

```
   MainActivity .class:
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Uri mImageCaptureUri;
private ImageView mImageView;

private static final int PICK_FROM_CAMERA = 1;
private static final int CROP_FROM_CAMERA = 2;
private static final int PICK_FROM_FILE = 3;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final String [] items           = new String [] {"Take from camera", "Select from gallery"};                
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter    = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,items);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder     = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setTitle("Select Image");
    builder.setAdapter( adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int item ) { //pick from camera
            if (item == 0) {
                Intent intent    = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                   "tmp_avatar_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));

                intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);

                try {
                    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

                    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else { //pick from file
                Intent intent = new Intent();

                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
            }
        }
    } );

    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

    Button button   = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_crop);
    mImageView      = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_photo);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;

    switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
            doCrop();

            break;

        case PICK_FROM_FILE: 
            mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();

            doCrop();

            break;          

        case CROP_FROM_CAMERA:          
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

            if (extras != null) {               
                Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");

                mImageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
            }

            File f = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());            

            if (f.exists()) f.delete();

            break;

    }
}

private void doCrop() {
    final ArrayList<CropOption> cropOptions = new ArrayList<CropOption>();

    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setType("image/*");

    List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( intent, 0 );

    int size = list.size();

    if (size == 0) {            
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can not find image crop app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return;
    } else {
        intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);

        intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent.putExtra("scale", true);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

        if (size == 1) {
            Intent i        = new Intent(intent);
            ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);

            i.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));

            startActivityForResult(i, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
        } else {
            for (ResolveInfo res : list) {
                final CropOption co = new CropOption();

                co.title    = getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                co.icon     = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                co.appIntent= new Intent(intent);

                co.appIntent.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));

                cropOptions.add(co);
            }

            CropOptionAdapter adapter = new CropOptionAdapter(getApplicationContext(), cropOptions);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Choose Crop App");
            builder.setAdapter( adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int item ) {
                    startActivityForResult( cropOptions.get(item).appIntent, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
                }
            });

            builder.setOnCancelListener( new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel( DialogInterface dialog ) {

                    if (mImageCaptureUri != null ) {
                        getContentResolver().delete(mImageCaptureUri, null, null );
                        mImageCaptureUri = null;
                    }
                }
            } );

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

            alert.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See if [this][1] answer can help you..

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228812/crop-image-android-android

Comment: thnkyou.. i think i also tried same like that only na..can you see my code once