# Custom image cropping : Android

Tags: java, android, image, image-processing, crop

I need to crop image taken from Camera or Gallery using image cropping technique.

I am aware of default image cropping in Android like [Crop image android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228812/crop-image-android-android) with rectangle cropping. But, my requirement is quite different than this.

Let me explain clearly. Lets take a look at below image.

[image]

Behind this image, my Camera/Gallery image will be there. I will be able to zoom that behind image(outer image is fixed). All the visible part from this outside image **white space** should be cropped and saved as image. Its like white space of the outer image acting like **camera preview** (window).

So, any clue or help about how I can implement this is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: hey @braj,did you find any thing on removing white spaces.

Comment: Try [this](https://github.com/lvillani/android-cropimage/blob/develop/src/com/android/camera/CropImage.java#L209)