# runtime exception in loading text reading library (tesseract) for OCR in eclipse juno

Tags: android, eclipse, ocr, tesseract

m working on android application that reads text from image, for this i have used tesseract tess-two library commonly used for this purpose. My idea is to select an image from gallery crop a portion of it for text reading, but when i crop a portion of image the application crashes and debug gives runtime load library exception error. In class file editor it says that sdk/platforms/android-15/android.jar has no source attachment. I ve properly imported the library in eclipse and then in my project. I have also tried it with different android platforms but it still gives the same error only the name of platform changes.
Plz help me get out of this issue would be great full for any kind of guidance provided.

Comment: See here how to crop image on android:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228812/crop-image-android-android

Comment: the issue is not in cropping image but in reading text from the copped image. If i remove the text reading code and just view the cropped image then its done properly.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse ,

Right click on project folder.
Go to properties.
In Properties window,
Go to "Java Build Path".
Select "Order and Export" Tab (from right portion)
Mark your library there.
Try to rebuild project.

Comment: I followed your idea but couldn't find my library in "Order and Export" Tab. The jar file for library is added in Android Dependencies option and that is marked in tab as well. How can i add the library itself in "Order and Export" tab?