# Crop and Save image android

Tags: android, camera

i am doing an android app that launches camera and capture an image, then crop and save the image. Then takes the image for some process.
i was trying with some suggestions and tutorials by searching on Google. but i am getting error after cropping. The image is being cropped and  actual image remains in SD-Card also the  cropped image saved as "image~2" in same location. but while we try to use the cropped image `filenotfoundException` is returned. Any one please help me.

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15239086/2009591)

Comment: You are talking on air. Without looking into your try or reference code, no one would be able to help you out!

Answer (score 0):

**"can i post my code?"**  - You should, actually, if you want some help here... Anyway considering the exception, you're searching for the image where it is not.

Or you can try this: https://github.com/edmodo/cropper

Comment: The link you posted does not exist anymore