# Crop Image Center using Screen Size

Tags: java, android, image

I've a Image 1280 x 853 in drawables directory. I want to crop that `Image` at the center using the Screen Size.

That's the way i get the `Screen Size`:

```
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
```

I thought it would be easy to pick the center of that `Image` and go half of screen `width` to left and the other half to the right.
I just don't know how to do that.

After I've cropped that Image i want to load it as `Splashscreen` Background.

I hope my reasoning is clear.

EDIT:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:background="@drawable/taskreport_splashscreen"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

Comment: Did you try `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`?

Comment: I tried but my background is still squished :/

Comment: Post the XML of the image. The whole XML block.

Comment: [Can you use default android Crop functionality? check out this solution hope it helps you][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15239086/3600674

Comment: It worked! android:scaleType="centerCrop" worked!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this property in your `ImageView`

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Comment: Is this the right solution for my Problem? because my Image is to wide, the Image get squished...thats why i want to crop just the center of that image

Comment: I've added the xml layout of that ImageView. It still is squished :/