# What is the most stable library for image cropping & rotating in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I just need to provide option to the users to crop and rotate an image, what would be the best you to do that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: That is your job to search on _google_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crop image android android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228812/crop-image-android-android)

Answer (score 2):

there lots of library which you can use

https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper

https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop

Comment: image cow is for php.

Comment: @user1569367 sorry that was my mistake. now look i updated the other one

Answer (score 1):

I am using this library in my application. this works like charm.

https://github.com/edmodo/cropper