# How to crop and rotate images taken from camera or selected from gallery before setting it to Imageview

Tags: android, android-camera

//Opening camera

```
    Intent cameraIntent = new  Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1888);
    //Setting Image
       if (requestCode == 1888 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
}
```

Comment: Just google for library to crop image. and will also find code to share image very very easily.

Answer (score 0):

> @Duplicate

You can see this marked answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228812/crop-image-in-android) com.android.camera.action.CROP is the key , you can search more and use default cropper.

You can do this method both Gallery and Camera. You just need Uri of photo..