# Crop Image on the fly

Tags: android, image, android-imageview, crop

I am working on a camera app.The camera preview show is with `4:3` ratio,When i take a photo i get the complete image or full screen image.

Since i am showing the user a Camera Preview with `4:3` ratio, i want the user to also get the image with 4:3 ratio only.

I have seen many libraries which gives the user an option to crop, but here as i give path of the image and then it should crop the image and display it to user.

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: The best library I found to crop images was [Android-Image-Cropper](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper). See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51985041/8383332).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think android has an out of the box cropper - but you can crop your own with `Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap, x1, y1, x2, y2)`

Comment: Chris,But what about the aspect ratio ?

Comment: You can ensure the new bitmap has the correct aspect ratio by calculating your coordinates correctly. You take the biggest 4:3 cutout of the bitmap.
Caveat though - this isn't likely to be a great experience for users, so you should create some on-screen window that displays where you're going to cut out the new image so they can adjust it.

Comment: I agree with @Chris, you should let the user confirm the crop and/or change the area. I used [this useful library](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.soundcloud.android/android-crop/0.9.10) to do it.

Comment: If you need some documentation you can look [here](https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop)

Comment: @Ayoub thanks, i dont want the user to be given an option to select arear to crop, just want to crop the image and display or save

Comment: The problem with that, is that you'll inevitably cut off someone's head from the picture and they won't be pleased

Answer (score 0):

Each Camera on each Android device has List of Preview Sizes and Picture Sizes.

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
List<Size> preview_sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
List<Size> pictures_sizes = parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();
```

Try to loop all this Sizes and pick 4:3. So your result will be 4:3 without cropping.

---

Read more [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/topics/media/camera.html).