# Android cropped image quality issue

Tags: android, image-processing, resize-crop, image-quality

I am trying to save an image as cropped from android and then show it in my app. I am using the code below, but when I try to view the image in my app the image quality is not good as in the attached image. Am doing anything wrong? Any help would be great.

[image: printscreeiphone6]

My code is:

```
dipToPixel = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 1, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && data != null) {

    picUri = data.getData();

    performCrop();

}


if (requestCode == 111 && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && data != null) {

        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

        Bitmap bitmapImage = extras.getParcelable("data");

        tweetImage.setImageBitmap(bitmapImage);

        tweetImage.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                tweetImage.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);

                widthPixel = tweetImage.getMeasuredWidth();
                heightPixel = tweetImage.getMeasuredHeight();

                return true;

            }
        });

        System.out.println("photo added");

        addPhotoVar = 1;
        addPhotoBtn.setText("remove");


}

callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


}


private void performCrop() {

try {

    //call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not support it)
    Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    //indicate image type and Uri
    cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
    //set crop properties
    cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    //indicate aspect of desired crop
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    //indicate output X and Y

    cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", Math.round(screenWidth / dipToPixel)-10);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", Math.round(screenWidth / dipToPixel)-10);
    //retrieve data on return
    cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
    startActivityForResult(cropIntent, 111);
}
// respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    // display an error message
    String errorMessage = "your device doesn't support the crop action!";
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}
}
```

Below is the code that I use the image and save to database:

```
                tweetImage.buildDrawingCache();
                bm = tweetImage.getDrawingCache();

                if (widthPixel < heightPixel) {

                    basePixel = widthPixel;

                }

                else {

                    basePixel = heightPixel;

                }


                if (basePixel > 768) {

                    widthRatio = (float) 768/basePixel;
                    heightRatio = (float) 768/basePixel;


                }

                else {

                    widthRatio = 1;
                    heightRatio = 1;

                }


                Bitmap bmResized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm,(int)(widthPixel*widthRatio), (int)(heightPixel*heightRatio), true);

                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bmResized.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                byteArray1 = stream.toByteArray();

                image1 = new ParseFile("profilePhoto.jpg", byteArray1, "image/jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

Change :

```
bmResized.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
```

to :

```
bmResized.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
```

Since `JPEG` format uses a lossy compression, you should use `PNG` to save the bitmap, if you don't want quality loss.

Also, you should avoid using `com.android.camera.action.CROP` intent as it doesn't exist on all the devices as explained [here](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html).

There are some alternatives listed on the above link, you may use one of them.

Comment: Consider though that the image will be larger when transitioning from JPEG to PNG.

Comment: yeah that will be a trade off, if you don't wanna lose quality.

Comment: may there also be a problem that causes the image to get smaller while using the line:   cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", Math.round(screenWidth / dipToPixel)-10);

Comment: no that's not a problem, also you should not use `com.android.camera.action.CROP` as this intent doesn't exist on all the devices.

Comment: try to log the values of `widthRatio`, `heightRatio`, `basePixel` and check if they are as expected?

Comment: No, I guess it is not about the jpg png issue. Somehow the output image becomes 315x315 pixels after cropping function.

Comment: try logging the values and check

Comment: 315x315 values comes right after the cropping I checked the log values of widthPixel and heightPixel. And when I use cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 768);   it is not working. I click on save after cropping and nothing happens.

Comment: `Math.round(screenWidth / dipToPixel)-10` value must be returning `315` , that's why you're getting 315x315 image, did you try both `outputX` & `outputY` as 768? i.e, `cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 768);cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 768);`

Answer (score 1):

Use this library, this library manage  cropped image quality as well it keeps both image [Crop Library](https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link :

https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html

Here are some libraries to consider for image crop:

```
https://github.com/lvillani/android-cropimage
https://github.com/biokys/cropimage
https://github.com/MMP-forTour/cropimage (forked from the above one)
https://github.com/dtitov/pickncrop
```