# How to crop image in Android?

Tags: android, bitmap, gallery, crop, provider

I want to pick image from gallery , then crop it by aspect ratio 1:1 , I already tried this :

[Crop image in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228812/crop-image-in-android)

It works fine on old Android versions , but not on ask 21+ , is there another solution for this ? Can I pass it to system to use for example Google photos or Snapseed to crop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It works fine on old Android versions

No, it does not. [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There is no requirement for any Android device to have an activity that supports the `Intent` demonstrated in the accepted answer on that question.

> is there another solution for this ?

You can use one of the many [image cropping libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45) that are available for Android.

Comment: Wow , actually that was so fast ! Thanks a lot