# how to crop images from recycleview and update recycleview with new cropped image?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, crop

I have created a recycle view, which consists of no of images that can be selected from the camera as well as the gallery, we have added two options to recycleview images that are deleted and crop option.
On Delete option click the recycleview item gets remove and recycleview gets update, Now I wish to implement crop functionality on recycleview images and add update them again to the recycleview.

following is working UI design on link 
https://ibb.co/kxXcnq

Following is crop option click event where i am getting the uri of the image: 
I have created this in seperate class of image adapter:

```
 holder.cropImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Show the removed item label`enter code here`

            File file = imagesFiles.get(position);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath());

            Log.d("file name :", file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can crop the image and save to the same Array List position in adapter and notify position of the apdater by using **adapter.notifyItemChanged(position);**

Comment: how I can perform crop operation on the image in an adapter which I have created separately, and update the receycleview.

Comment: @ReceiptBag Is your cropping code static(Means you crop the bitmap area with same height and width for example cropping image in 1:1 ratio)

Answer (score 0):

1. Pass the selected Image from Adapter to this libraries activities https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper after cropping you will get result
2. Then i think you will get the position of image so u update with new image in the list

Comment: I tried applying the library already, it giving me nothing, it does not start the crop actvity  

`File file = imagesFiles.get(position);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath());
AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();   
CropImage.activity(uri).start(activity);`

Comment: @ReceiptBag What's this?

Comment: i am getting uri of the selected image from recycleview, that image i have to open with the crop library, i have already pass the uri to CropImage Class which opens the crop activity in order to crop the image with the uri

Comment: @ReceiptBag ok what's the problem?

Comment: as per your instruction i have implemented Image-Cropper library,
// this two lines gives me image file in form of uri
`File file = imagesFiles.get(position); 
Uri uri = Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath());`
// gets activity from adapter class in order to use in next line code
`AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();`
// this is used to crop the image with uri, it opens the crop activity
`CropImage.activity(uri).start(activity);`
but this line of code does not start any crop activity, it just does not do anything.

Comment: @ReceiptBag try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228812/crop-image-in-android 
OR
https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop