# Android select and Crop Image using single Intent

Tags: android, image-processing, android-intent, crop

I have to use two different intents, one to select an image and the other to crop the image.

Is there any way out to use a single Intent to select and crop the Image.

The below code only selects the image but does not crop it -

```
Uri outuri = Uri.fromFile(createFile(path));
//GalIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
//GalIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        GalIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        GalIntent.setType("image/*");
        GalIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        GalIntent.putExtra("outputX", 1000);
        GalIntent.putExtra("outputY", 1000);
        GalIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 10);
        GalIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 10);
        GalIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outuri);
        GalIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
        GalIntent.putExtra("return-data", false);
        startActivityForResult(GalIntent, 1);
```

I have to get the intent data onActivityResult and start another intent to crop the data -

```
CropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        CropIntent.setDataAndType(imageUri, "image/*");
        CropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        CropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 1000);
        CropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 1000);
        CropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 10);
        CropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 10);
        //CropIntent.putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded", true);
        CropIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outuri);
        CropIntent.putExtra("return-data", false);
        //CropIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
        startActivityForResult(CropIntent, 1);
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228812/crop-image-in-android same as your use case.

Comment: @rasfarrf5 that answer is also using an image uri to start the crop intent, it does not select the image using the same intent.